# Remove some files from latest commit

Tags: git

Some of my lastly commited files are unfortunately too big for github, so I would like to remove these from the latest commit, making it possible to push the other files. I have tried using git reset --HEAD for this, but it seems to only work if you haven't commited the files yet. Any other ideas?

Comment: how big is the file that github rejects? Is it a binary?

Comment: @MitchWheat There are two of them, one is a ~150MB text file, the other a ~120MB binary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

1. `git rm` the offending files
2. `git status` should show the files as deleted
3. `git commit --amend` to amend the last commit, the files should no longer be included
4. `git push`

See this transcript:

```
[root@/tmp/test master]touch b c
[root@/tmp/test master]git add b c
[root@/tmp/test master]git commit -m "Add b and c"
[master 1cd809f] Add b and c
 0 files changed
 create mode 100644 b
 create mode 100644 c
[root@/tmp/test master]git rm c
rm 'c'
[root@/tmp/test master]git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       deleted:    c
#
[root@/tmp/test master]git commit --amend -m "Add only b"
[master 9c5809e] Add only b
 0 files changed
 create mode 100644 b
[root@/tmp/test master]git diff HEAD^..HEAD
diff --git a/b b/b
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..e69de29
```

**Note:** This only works if the offending files were added in the last commit. In other cases refer to [Remove sensitive data in the GitHub help](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data), it explains to delete a file from the complete history.

In case this it not wanted either you can try an interactive rebase (`git rebase -i <commitish>`) and my method above.

Comment: Also useful in the context is `git rm --cached` which only removes the files from the index, but leaves them in the working tree.